# Log iptables events on centos 7

Tags: centos, iptables, logs, dmesg

I have got iptables on my centos 7. My firewalld is disabled.
How can I log my iptables events? On debian it is dmesg option but I don't know how to set it on centos.

I want to log all of my iptables events. Not specific rule.

Comment: Are you asking how to *enable* or how to *see* the logs? Because frankly, `dmesg` won't enable logging of netfilter rules, you'll have to tell netfilter to log matching packets using the `LOG` target (and that's independent of the question if this is Debian or CentOS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the best solution for me:
Warning level:

```
iptables -A INPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "BAD_INPUT: " --log-level 4
iptables -A FORWARD -j LOG --log-prefix "BAD_FORWARD: " --log-level 4
iptables -A OUTPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "BAD_OUTPUT: " --log-level 4
```

Debug level:

```
iptables -A INPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "BAD_INPUT: " --log-level 7
iptables -A FORWARD -j LOG --log-prefix "BAD_FORWARD: " --log-level 7
iptables -A OUTPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "BAD_OUTPUT: " --log-level 7
```

Logs are storred in:

```
/var/log/messages
```

Sample output:

```
Aug  4 13:22:40 centos kernel: BAD_INPUT: IN= OUT=em1 SRC=192.168.1.23 DST=192.168.1.20 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=59228 SEQ=2
Aug  4 13:23:00 centos kernel: BAD_INPUT: IN=em1 OUT= MAC=a2:be:d2:ab:11:af:e2:f2:00:00 SRC=192.168.2.115 DST=192.168.1.23 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=9434 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=58428 DPT=443 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

Comment: This is wrong because in CentOS 7+ the logs are handld by journald/journalctrl and then the kernel logs (iptables) are not sent to /var/log files (unless you revert the log configuration to pre CentOS6 style).

The right way to check your iptables and other kernel logs is to use journalctl like this:
    journalctl -k

Answer (score 6):

When a packet matches a `iptables ... -j LOG` rule, a kernel log message is generated. You can specify the severity level of the message using the `--log-level <level>` option, where the `<level>` can be one of the standard syslog level identifiers: `emerg`, `alert`, `crit`, `error`, `warning`, `notice`, `info` or `debug`.

These log messages are processed by `rsyslog`: if the severity level is low enough, `rsyslog` may completely discard the messages. Since the iptables log messages come from the kernel, their logging category will always be `kern`. So look into `/etc/rsyslog.conf` to see which is the minimum severity level for `kern.*` messages to be acted on, and into which log file they will be stored into. Then set an appropriate severity level to your `iptables -j LOG` rules.

Or use the `iptables ... -j LOG --log-prefix <prefix>` option to add an identifiable prefix to iptables messages, and then use the advanced features of `rsyslog` to write the iptables messages into a separate log file.

Comment: I want to log all of my iptables events. Not specific rule.

Comment: Then place a LOG rule at the start of INPUT, OUTPUT and FORWARD chains. You will then get a log message of **every IP packet** your system sends and receives. This may be useful in some troubleshooting situations in isolated networks, but in a typical internet-connected system it is just a good way to fill up your disk with logs. Or... please describe what you think of as an "event"?

Answer (score 1):

CentOS 7 uses systemd's journald as the default logs system, and with this the kernel logs (like the ones from **iptables**) are not directed to `/var/log/messages` but to journald and should be displayed by passing the `-k` (meaning kernel logs) to journalctl like this:

```
journalctl -k
```

Check the man of journalctl [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journalctl.html)
or any of the many tutorials in the net to find out all the options; but most probably you will use `-f` to follow the logs, `-b` to include only logs since the previos boot, `--since` to select logs by date or `--no-pager` to disable the default pager on the output.

To generate the logs you will have to use the `-j LOG` action with iptables as stated in other responses, and most probably you will like to include `--limit` to prevent from flooding your logs:

```
iptables -A INPUT -j LOG -limit 1/s --limit-burst 3 --log-prefix "INPUT REJECTED: " --log-level 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enable logging by this command (for example for INPUT chain):

```
iptables -A INPUT -j LOG
```

Answer (score 0):

iptables logs events to `/var/log/messages` in CentOS 7.